# Compute checksum of python script/module and all recursive imports, including standard libs

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, checksum

I'd like to be able to check for equality of two python codebases. I need to check imports (recursively) in case any of them are different, including differences in stdlib versions (although I don't care about differences of the Python interpreter itself). I have nixed the idea of simply walking my `/source/` directory and computing the checksum of each file, because there may be source files that are unused. I can use the `ast` lib to walk all the `import` declarations, but I don't know how to get the AST of a stdlib, even if I do (dangerously) resolve the lib names to their respective filenames. What are my options?

Comment: How do you plan to handle Python built-in modules implemented in C? Does it really matter if you checksum the unused files? It's going to be nigh impossible to definitively determine if a file is unused after all (modules can be imported dynamically in several ways, so it's basically impossible to be sure if they're used or not by any means short of running the process in as many varied ways as possible, while debugging to check the cached modules in `sys.modules`).